# Gearbox issues VW Bora MK5 (Bora in Mex) 2007

Tags: vw, transmission, automatic-transmission, bora

I've been driving my VW Bora for 7 years. Has had its regular oil changes, tune-ups, tires and brake changes. I love my car and want to keep it perfect. For the last 6 months I have felt that the automatic gearbox abnormaly changes gears. This happens after 10-15 minutes of regular soft driving. It is ussualy felt when changing from 2nd to 3rd, or 3rd to 4th, sometimes the revs go up to 3k and then I hear and feel a strong hit. I took my car to the dealership and they told me that the gearbox is sealed and that noone takes a look at it, this also happned on a Grease Monkey store, they dont service VW auto transmissions. Should I be worried about transmission fluid or something? Is there any place thtat It can be looked at? I think I have read previously about sediments but it seems to me pretty strange that this kind of service is not included. Thank you for your comments. 
Edit: 86K kilometers or 53K miles.

Comment: If you brought the car to a VW dealership, it makes no sense why they wouldn't look at it. They should be able to take a look or at least flush your transmission to try and resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty sure VW Mexico is covering their failures by not accepting maintenance, I've sent a request to service to scan it. Mexican VW enthuasiast forums are bombarded with transmission failures. Let us see how this goes.